# What is the difference between Android Studio and frameworks?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, xamarin, frameworks

I have seen many people recommending frameworks like Ionic, Xamarin, Flutter, React Native etc for developing Android apps. However, I have been coding in Android Studio using Java and Kotlin and have made a few apps.

So what is the difference between these frameworks and Android Studio? How are they better than Android Studio? 
I know Android Studio is an IDE but don't these frameworks also compile and run your code to create an Android app? So what's the difference?

Comment: android studio isn't a framework, you can't compare a framework (Flutter, xamarin, etc) to an IDE. you can also very easily do research to discover the pros and cons (as a lot of these are based on experience and opinion) by simply visiting each of the frameworks you want to learn more about

Answer (score 1):

Android studio is for developing android apps. Frameworks like react native and ionic are for developing apps that run natively on both android and ios devices.

If you make an app in android studio, then want to support ios, you start from scratch. With a framework like RN, you write higher level javascript code that is mapped to native java/kotlin for android, and native objectiveC/swift for ios. Depending on the complexity of your app you will still need to do a little bit of native work in android studio/xcode, but for the most part your work will be in the higher level language, and it will simply work on both android and ios devices.

If you don't care about ios at all, these don't really matter, but if you want to develop for both it can help you do that in half the time it would normally take.

Answer (score 1):

frameworks like Ionic, Xamarin, Flutter, React Native etc allows you to develop apps which can be deployed in multiple platforms like Android, iOS, Web..